# Need to call third party API from Salesforce using task trigger

Tags: apex, callout

I need to call 3rd party API using Triggers. Here is the below code which i used. But i got "Error: Compile Error: unexpected syntax: 'missing EOF at 'trigger'' at line 16 column 1" Error. Anyone please guide me to fix this issue.

**My focus is after insert the Task or Case i need to call third party SOAP API for further process. if this not suitable could you please suggest me some other idea**

```
public class CalloutClass {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void makeCallout() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        // Set the endpoint URL.
        String endpoint = 'API url';
        request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
        // Set the HTTP verb to GET.
        request.setMethod('GET');
        // Send the HTTP request and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = new HTTP().send(request);
        return response;
    }
}

trigger ContextExampleTriggerr on Task (after insert) {
    CalloutClass.makeCallout();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file (e.g. trigger) can only have one top-level object. You will need to create your class as a class. Also, future methods are "void" because they cannot return a value. Remove the final line from the makeCallout method. Finally, presumably, you'll want to pass a parameter to your class so it knows which tasks it needs to process. At minimum, your changes would need to look like this:

```
public class CalloutClass {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void makeCallout(Set<Id> taskIds) {
        Task[] taskRecords = [select id from task where id = :taskIds];
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        // Set the endpoint URL.
        String endpoint = 'API url';
        request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
        // Set the HTTP verb to GET.
        request.setMethod('GET');
        // Send the HTTP request and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = new HTTP().send(request);
    }
}
```

---

```
trigger ContextExampleTriggerr on Task (after insert) {
    CalloutClass.makeCallout(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

---

You might also consider using a less generic name than CalloutClass and makeCallout. The names are nondescript, and so are not self-documenting. I realize that this is apparently "just to test out", but even so, if you get in to a habit of doing this, you, or your peers/predecessors/etc will not know what this code is meant to do when you need to update the code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a return statement in a void method. I am able to save the class and trigger after removing return statement.

Comment: please make sure you provide a detailed explanation of why this answer is suitable, additionally, does this address all the above users concerns? this would seem more like a good comment under the post itself rather than an answer as mentioned in [answer].